# Unprotected Excel Sheet Runtime 1004 error - can't set numberformat of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple sub running on togglebutton click as part of a larger vba project. Neither the workbook or sheet are protected. I want to set the format of an output cell (E18 on the same sheet as the button) to match the units the formula is calculated in. The errors occur on the commented-out lines. Without the format lines the sub and the larger project both work perfectly fine.

```
Private Sub ToggleButtonLB_Click()

If ToggleButtonLB.Value = True Then
    ToggleButtonLB.Caption = "kg"
    'Range("E18").NumberFormat = "0.0 kg"
    
    Else
    ToggleButtonLB.Caption = "lb"
    'Range("E18").NumberFormat = "0.0 lb"
End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the macro recorder and change the cell to your desired format, you will get:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0 ""kg"""
```

So in your code, try:

```
Private Sub ToggleButtonLB_Click()

If ToggleButtonLB.Value = True Then
    ToggleButtonLB.Caption = "kg"
    Range("E18").NumberFormat = "0.0 ""kg"""
    
    Else
    ToggleButtonLB.Caption = "lb"
    Range("E18").NumberFormat = "0.0 ""lb"""
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!  Can you explain why the format needs to be broken up and why the extra empty quotes at the end are necessary?  I don't understand either of those - all documents I looked at suggested 1 quote encompassing the entire format with no empty "" at the end

Comment: They actually aren't empty quotes, there are 3 levels of quotes. The outermost quotes indicate `0.0 ""lb""` is the string you want to use for your format. The next outermost quotes around `lb` indicate you want to include the inner quotation marks in your string. The innermost quotes indicate the letters `lb` should be taken as a literal string in your number format code.